# X and Y are two independent random variables, and are standard normal. Determine $P(X\lt Y \lt 2X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X and Y are two independent  random variables, and are standard normal. Determine $P(X\lt Y \lt 2X)$.

I'm having difficulties understanding how to solve this and would appreciate any hints or steps.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The set $\{(x,y):x<y<2x\}$ is a radial wedge (make a drawing). Do you know the probability density $f_{X,Y}(x,y) $ ?

If so write down an integral and change to polar coordinates. This is probably recommendable as a good exercise in integration.

But, even simpler is to notice that the wedge is angular symmetric and so is the PDF. The probability is therefore proportional to the angle spanned by the two radial half-lines bounding the domain. So  the result, $\frac{\tan^{-1}(2)-\tan^{-1}(1)}{2\pi}=\frac{\tan^{-1}(2)}{2\pi}-\frac18$ may be obtained essentially without calculations.

Comment: That far I've understood. But we're looking for 

$Pr(1 \lt \frac{y}{x} \lt 2)$, and when multiplying $f_x(\frac{1}{X})$ and $f_y(Y)$ I don't get anything that I can change to polar coordinates.

Comment: No you shouldn't write it like this (don't divide by $x$). The sets for which $y>x$ and $y<2x$, respectively, are two half planes and their intersection is quite simple once you make a drawing (and is well expressed in polar coordinates).

Comment: So my integral should be $\integral^{\infty}_{\infty} e^{-x^2/2)dx*$$\integral^{x}_{2x} e^{-y^2/2)$ My problem is changing the limits when switching over to polar coordinates

Comment: Better write $\Omega=\{(x,y): x<y<2x\}$ and notice in polar coordinates this is $\Omega'=\{(r,\phi) \in [0,+\infty)\times [0,2\pi): r>0, u<\phi<v \}$ for suitable $u$ and $v$ that you should find (again I recommend making a drawing). After that $dx\; dy=r \; dr\; d\phi$

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y<2X)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{2x}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)dydx$$
set
$$x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta$$
hence
$$1\le \frac{y}{x}\le 2$$
thus
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le \tan^{-1}(2)$$
finally, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y<2X)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}r\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2}\right)drd\theta$$
$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y<2X)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\tan^{-1}(2)}d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\tan^{-1}(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Comment: @ H. H. Rugh So thanks. You are right.